# how to add double quotes to a string in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with words that are each in a separate line. I want to read each word and add quotes around it, and a comma after the word. After that I want the words back into a new text file with the added symbols.

Example, this as input file:

```
ram 
shyam
raja
```

I want this to be in the output file:

```
"ram",
"shyam",
"raja"
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* contents of the input and desired output. Is it  a single line of three words, or three separate lines?

Comment: Please format the input and output **EXACTLY** as you want it. There's no way for us to solve it if we don't know what you're getting and what you want to get back

Comment: Do `str = '"' + str + '"'` to each line.

Answer (score 2):

If each word is on the same line of the input file, separated by spaces. Then you could approach it like this:

```py
# read lines from file
text = ""
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as ifile:
    text = ifile.readline()

# get all sepearte string split by space
data = text.split(" ")

# add quotes to each one
data = [f"\"{name}\"" for name in data]

# append them together with commas inbetween
updated_text = ", ".join(data)

# write to some file
with open("outfilename.txt", 'w') as ofile:
    ofile.write(updated_text)
```

Input:

```
jeff adam bezos
```

Output

```
"jeff", "adam", "bezos"
```

If you want to work with each input and output file word on a separate line, we could take this approach:

```py
# read lines from file
words = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as ifile:
    words = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in ifile.readlines()]

# add quotes to each one
updated_words = [f"\"{word}\"" for word in words]

# append them together with commas inbetween
updated_text = ",\n".join(updated_words)

# write to some file
with open("outfilename.txt", 'w') as ofile:
    ofile.write(updated_text)
```

Input:

```
jeff
adam
bezos
```

Output

```
"jeff",
"adam",
"bezos"
```

Good Luck!

Comment: this works too but for a text in a single row, not column.

Comment: Do you need a solution with everything word on a different line?

Comment: @SatyamShishodiya I added a solution for when each word is on a separate line.

Comment: hi need help with one more problem please ping when available.

Comment: @SatyamShishodiya link your new question to me here.

Comment: Hi can you connect to me over mail.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file as list using read().splitlines() and write the line using f-string and writelines:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as r: lines = r.read().splitlines()
with open('text.txt', 'w') as w: w.writelines(f'"{line}",'+'\n' for line in lines)
```